# Joining multiple lists containing multiple dictionaries to make a list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have two lists, each containing dictionaries:

```
list1 = [{'user':'John'},{'user':'Micheal'},{'user':'Sara'}]
list2 = [{'Status':'Active'},{'Status':'Active'},{'Status':'Inactive'}]
```

The values correspond betweeen the lists, like the index 0 of both lists shows that the user John is active and index 1 of both lists show that the user Michael is inactive. 
I want to create a new function which would do this:

```
listsjoiner(list1,list2)
```

Output:

```
[{'user':'John','Status':'Active'},{'user':'Michael','status':'Active'},['user':'Sara','status':'Inactive}]
```

Comment: Look at the zip function

Comment: It doesn't join the dictionaries in the list, it just binds them in a tuple and returns them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it appears that both lists are ordered in the sequence that you would like them joined, you can use list comprehension along with the `*` operator (splatting) to get the result you want. For example:

```
list1 = [{'user':'John'},{'user':'Micheal'},{'user':'Sara'}]
list2 = [{'Status':'Active'},{'Status':'Active'},{'Status':'Inactive'}]

results = [{**list1[i], **list2[i]} for i in range(len(list1))]

print(results)

# OUTPUT
# [{'user': 'John', 'Status': 'Active'}, {'user': 'Micheal', 'Status': 'Active'}, {'user': 'Sara', 'Status': 'Inactive'}]
```

Comment: thanks a lot man, it took me ages to surf the documentation but couldn't find a way to nest them

Answer (score 2):

This is what I meant by looking at the `zip` function:

```
>>> result = [{**user_dict, **status_dict} for user_dict, status_dict in zip(list1, list2)]
>>> result
[{'user': 'John', 'Status': 'Active'}, {'user': 'Micheal', 'Status': 'Active'}, {'user': 'Sara', 'Status': 'Inactive'}]
```

Comment: This seems more pythonic than benvc's answer

Comment: @IliaGilmijarow this answer also runs a little faster on average than mine.